# Changing timezone for a default timestamp column in Snowflake

Tags: timezone, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table defined in snowflake as follows;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE DATA_LAKE.CUSTOMER.ACT_PREDICTED_PROBABILITIES(
PREDICTED_PROBABILITY FLOAT,
TIME_PREDICTED TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 );
```

As expected default timezone is America/Los Angeles. I am trying to change it to UTC, but only for this column, not at account/session level.Here is the code I wrote;

```
ALTER TABLE  DATA_LAKE.CUSTOMER.ACT_PREDICTED_PROBABILITIES ALTER TIME_PREDICTED  SET    timezone=  'UTC';
```

But it is giving an error,

```
SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 86 unexpected 'timezone'.
```

Can I please get help on how to do the change at column level?thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reviewing this documentation regarding `timestamp` data types:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html#timestamp

However, assuming that your `TIMESTAMP_TYPE_MAPPING` is still the default of `TIMESTAMP_NTZ`, then you've now got a bunch of data that is set to America/Los Angeles without a timezone offset in the values, and if you're not going to change any of your account timezone settings, then you either need to leave it that way and just change the timezone as you select the data using the `CONVERT_TIMEZONE` function, or you should change your table definition to a data type that includes a timezone offset.  You could also update the column as it is by converting it with the same `CONVERT_TIMEZONE` function, but then future data would still be inserted using America/Los Angeles timezone.

My recommendation is to use `TIMESTAMP_TZ` as your column type and modify the current data accordingly.

Comment: Appreciate your reply. So if I am understanding it correctly, are you saying that I shoud change the table definition and that involves dropping the table and then defining it again. Am I understanding it correct?